# Regex in bash not giving back the results expecting

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to use regex to extract some info from a df. However the information that I'm getting back isn't what I'm expecting.

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

disk_info=$(df -hT /var/lib/mysql)
regex="([0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*[GM]*) ([0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*[GM]*) ([0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*[GM]*) ([0-9]*)% \/var\/lib\/mysql$"

if [[ $disk_info =~ $regex ]]
then
    full_string="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
    size="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    used="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    avail="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    usage="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"

    echo "full string before regex is: $disk_info"
    echo "full string is: $full_string"
    echo "size of db is: $size"
    echo "used by db is: $used"
    echo "available on db is: $avail"
    echo "usage in percent on db is: $usage"
else
    echo "$disk_info doesn't match" >&2
fi
```

The regex is used to extract 4 matching groups. Namely the entire size that is allocated for mysql, the amount used, how much is available and lastly the usage of disk space in %. Now the size, used and avail returns the size in either gigabytes or megabytes and can contain a dot that's why I made the regex the way I did.

The problem lies in the output that I get when I run this. The return is:

```
full string before regex is: Filesystem           Type  Size  Used Avail     Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_db
                 ext3   21G   11G  9.2G  54% /var/lib/mysql
full string after regex is:  9.2G  54% /var/lib/mysql
size of db is:
used by db is: 9.2G
available on db is:
usage in percent on db is: 54
```

As you can see, the string after the regex only gives back half the numbers. I think it has to do with the dot missing in the first 2. Another problem is that the order seems to be messed up since the 9.2G should listed with "available on db is:" and not the "used by db is:"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't want to have atleast one match for the dots or the tens digit since it could have 5G flat. So it honestly depends in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input contains not just a single space as a separator. Use \s+ instead a single space:

```
regex="([0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*[GM]*)\s+([0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*[GM]*)\s+([0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*[GM]*)\s+([0-9]*)% \/var\/lib\/mysql$"
```

Comment: Yep that fixed it. The formatting must have differed when I pasted the test string. Thanks!